# Can BZ2_bzBuffToBuffCompress() be called repeatedly?

Tags: c, compression, bzip2

I have a large amount of "input" data that I want to compress to multiple `bzip2` streams, without writing data to multiple intermediate files.

Can I put a chunk of input data into a buffer, use `BZ2_bzBuffToBuffCompress()` to compress that buffer to bzip2-flavored bytes, and repeat with subsequent `BZ2_bzBuffToBuffCompress()` calls on fresh data, until I have no more input data left?

The [bzip2 documentation](http://www.bzip.org/1.0.3/html/util-fns.html) says the following:

> Compression in this manner is a one-shot event, done with a single call to this function. The resulting compressed data is a complete bzip2 format data stream. There is no mechanism for making additional calls to provide extra input data. If you want that kind of mechanism, use the low-level interface.

Does this mean I cannot re-run `BZ2_bzBuffToBuffCompress()` on newly filled buffer-sized chunks of input data? Should I use `BZ2_bzWrite()` instead?

**EDIT**

I actually meant outputting to one archive file, which could contain one or more bzip streams.

Comment: My understanding when reading the documentation is that you can not add (append) more data to an already compressed buffer, but creating multiple separate compressed streams or buffers is okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep calling `BZ2_bzBuffToBuffCompress()` with new data all you like, and you will generate what I think you said you wanted, which was:

> data that I want to compress to multiple bzip2 streams

That is exactly what you'll get.  Multiple bzip2 streams.  Each of those streams then needs to be separately decoded.

If you want to take a series of buffers and make a *single* bzip2 stream out of them, then you will need to use `BZ2_bzCompressInit`, `BZ2_bzCompress`, and `BZ2_bzCompressEnd`.

Comment: Thanks, I think your second suggestion is what I had in mind. I'll test this out and mark your answer as correct once I've verified this.